# Is Adaptive card designer tool opensource?

Tags: adaptive-cards

Just wanted to see if the designer tool is opensource. Couldn't see it in GitHub repo. If not are there any plans to opensource the designer tool https://adaptivecards.io/designer/

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 2):

Source can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/tree/master/source/nodejs/adaptivecards-designer

There is also an npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards-designer